# CLion IDE (CMake): Project builds but no intelligence for external libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, glfw

I've implemented the [GLFW basic example](https://www.glfw.org/documentation.html).

The GLFW header file is reported as not being found and such the CLion IDE is reporting and error and not providing intellisense however the project correctly compiles and runs.

I've added the GLFW library as per the guidance in their [documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build.html) (See CMakeLists.txt).

The project is being built and run remotely on Ubuntu 20.04.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    ...
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(untitled1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)


find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)

add_executable(untitled1 ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(untitled1 glfw)
```

Comment: Where do you `target_include_directories` the GLFW header directory? FindGLFW3.cmake exposed `GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIRS ` and `GLFW3_LIBRARIES ` variables.

Comment: Wait, you're building this remotely? Shouldn't your local system also have a glfw3 install in order for clion to see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone encountering this issue call *Tools | Resync with Remote Hosts -*